# Not able to click an element on span

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a guide wire claim application. the element i am trying to click is a triangle. I have attached the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWXnU.png) with HTML. I have used the xpath `-//*[@id='TabBar:ClaimTab-btnWrap']-` but it is not the correct xpath since it  taking me to next page not which is not we are expecting. we are expecting to show us a menu bar. I research online and tried all the method such as. Hoverandclick using xoffset,yoffset. nothing is working. Can someone give us any suggestion. I am using C# for coding.
My code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action
 .MoveToElement(elementToHover, 24, 0)
 .ContextClick(elementToClick)
 .Build()
 .Perform();
```

Can anyone please suggest some solution [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT5xr.png)

HTML:

 
 

 
C
laim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please send Arrow_down key using sendkeys method after click on that tab. This is the only way.